# Is there any way to print the excel sheet using office Js?

Tags: excel, printing, office-js, office-addins, excel-web-addins

Is there any other way to print the excel sheet or any way to trigger print button of excel?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/

I have searched a lot in office JS documentation. But, not getting any solution for print the excel sheet. I think not any API available in the office JS for print the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot print Excel sheets directly from the office js API.
However, you can use a workaround by exporting the Excel sheet to a PDF and then triggering the print dialog for the PDF, like this:

```
// Function to export Excel sheet to PDF
function exportSheetToPDF(context) {
    // Replace with your sheet name
    let sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("YourSheetName");

// Get the used range of the sheet
let range = sheet.getUsedRange();
range.load("address");

// Run the batch operation
return context.sync().then(function() {
    // Replace with your logic to export the range to PDF
    // This part depends on your application's capabilities
});
}

// Function to trigger print dialog on the PDF
function printPDF(pdfUrl) {
    let win = window.open(pdfUrl, '_blank');
    win.focus();
    win.onload = function() {
        win.print();
    };
}

// Usage
Excel.run(function (context) {
    return exportSheetToPDF(context);
}).then(function (pdfUrl) {
    printPDF(pdfUrl);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Steven your code is working. I have got pdf data of worksheet using getFileAsync and that I have convert that bytes to blob URL and passed that URL in your code.

Comment: But, I haven't got any solution for get bytes data of specific range. Currently getting bytes of full worksheet.